# Livewire offcanvas Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, laravel-livewire, off-canvas-menu

I work with Livewire and Bootstrap 5. I have in a Livewire component an Offcanvas that is displayed when a button is clicked. In this canvas I have a text area which via LiveWire makes a request to the server.

This request makes the offcanvas disappear while I want it to remain displayed. For that I use wire:ignore-self.  This works well but the overlay does not stay because it is generated via Bootstrap so it is not possible to put it in ignore-self. How to do it

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample"
         aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel" wire:ignore-self>
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">Head</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
                    aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <div>
                   Header
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                    <label for="xda" class="form-label">Text</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Text"
                           id="xda" name="xda" wire:model="xda">
                </div>
                <hr>
                
    </div>
```

Comment: isn't wire:ignore-self, instead write it like wire:ignore.self

Comment: Hey, did you ever found a solution? I have the exact same question

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Basically, the overlay is generated as a sibling to the offcanvas itself. So, for it to remain on screen when livewire updates the content, you have to wrap the offcanvas element in a `<div wire:ignore>`.

If the offcanvas content contains element that are relevant to livewire, in my case inputs with wire:model, you will have to use Alpine's `@change="$dispatch('input', $el.value)"` on the input so the wire model updates as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, having a select as input, it was enough to insert `wire:ignore.self` in the main div of the offcanvas; `wire:ignore` didn't update the data.

[Reference](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1389#issuecomment-677531236)